# Multiple statements in Javascript anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

*(Didn't find this Q while searching, but might be a matter of not knowing the terms for which to search)*

Trying to mimic range() using code I found on SO (learning the language, so avoiding using ready-made functions in underscore.js), and I'm having trouble understanding why this will work:

```
var range = Array.apply(null,Array(3));

range = range.map(function (x, i) {return i;});
```

But this does not:

```
var range = Array.apply(null,Array(3));

range = range.map(function (x, i) {
    console.log(range[i-1]);
    return i;
});

< undefined
< undefined
< undefined
```

Ostensibly only difference is the `console.log` line, but why should that matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They both are *returning* the same exact thing `[0, 1, 2]` - the only difference I can see in the output is the 3 `undefined`s printed out by the `console.log()` statement (which is to be expected since `x` is the actual array element and not the index).

Comment: thanks! 'x' was a dumb typo, but the 'undefined' msgs still pumped out when it was corrected.  I'll edit the code, but @ShadowRanger explained it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is creating an array of size 3, but the values will all be undefined. When you iterate it with `map` (to make a new `range`), you're logging by indexing; `range[x - i]` in the first loop is looking at `range[undefined - 0]` (becomes `range[0]`), and subsequent loops look at `range[-1]`, etc. Of course they're `undefined`. Until the `map` completes, `range` has not been reassigned, so all you'll ever get is `undefined.` When the `map` completes though, with or without the `log`, `range` will be `[0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: thanks - i was operating under the assumption that each element of the array was reassigned after map() iterated over it.  Good to know how it really works.